# How to convert Map<String,Object> into Map<string,string>()?

Tags: apex

I have map value like

```
 mapModelLabel >>>>>{GM2 E3A MC M=GM2 E3A MC M, GM2 E3A MS M=GM2 E3A MS M}
```

code

```
strJSON= res.getBody();
    system.debug('strJson>>>>>'+strJSON);

Map<String,Object> mapJSON = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(strJSON);
Map<String,Object> mapLocalSemi = (Map<String,Object>)mapJSON.get('localSemiClair');
Map<String,Object> mapMapRep = (Map<String,Object>)mapLocalSemi .get('mapRepresentation'); 
Map<String,Object> mapValues = (Map<String,Object>)mapMapRep.get('map');
```

I want to convert into map

how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can try like this

```
map<string,string> newMap= new Map<string,string>();
for(String strKey: mapValues.keyset())
{
    newMap.put(strKey, String.valueof(mapValues.get(strKey)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this worked for me:

enter code here

```
map<string,object> mspstrToObj = new Map<string,object>();
mspstrToObj.put('key1', 'obj1');

map<string,string> mspstrTostr = new Map<string,string>();

mspstrTostr.put('strKey1',string.valueof(mspstrToObj.get('key1')));

system.debug('=======mspstrTostr====='+mspstrTostr);
```

You need to create new Map and put the values as per above.